# Emacs - Magit reuse same window for different project when switching window

Tags: emacs, magit

I'm a new user of `magit` and I'm currently using it in a separate frame with a single window (`magit-status`). I'd like that to show the git status of the project of the latest visited buffer. Imagine that in another frame I have two windows with two buffers of files of two different projects. I'd like the `magit` window to show me the git status of the project depending on the current selected window.

```
        frame 1                  frame 2
***********************     ****************  
* window 1 * window 2 *     *    window3   *
*          *          *     *              *
*   file   *   file   *     * magit-status *
* of proj1 * of proj2 *     *              *
*          *          *     *              *
***********************     ****************
```

To be clearer if the selected window is `window 1` I'd like `window 3` to show the status for project 1, then if I change to `window 2` I'd like `window 3` to show the status for project 2.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't understand question - if you execute `magit-status` from current buffer, then it will show status for repository with this file.

Comment: @AlexOtt yes, but it will open the buffer in another window, I'd like that the already opened buffer `*magit: <other-project-name>` is refreshed for the project of the current buffer.

Comment: @AlexOtt I've updated the question

Comment: This discussion could be relevant: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2541

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final solution that I'm using thanks to the answer here:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36718/magit-reuse-same-window-for-different-project-when-switching-window

```
(defun magit-status-autorefresh (callee)
  (interactive)
  (let ((project-previous (magit-toplevel)))
    (call-interactively callee)
    (let ((project (magit-toplevel)))
      (when (and project
                 (not (equal project-previous project)))
        (let ((status-win
               (cl-some (lambda (b)
                          (and (with-current-buffer b
                                 (derived-mode-p 'magit-status-mode))
                               (get-buffer-window b 'visible)))
                        (buffer-list)))
              (magit-display-buffer-noselect t)
              (magit-display-buffer-function
               (lambda (buffer)
                 (display-buffer buffer '(display-buffer-same-window)))))
          (when status-win
            (with-selected-frame (window-frame status-win)
              (with-selected-window status-win
                (magit-status-internal project))))))))
  )

(defun my/other-window ()
  (interactive)
  (magit-status-autorefresh 'other-window)
  )

(defun my/other-counsel-projectile-find-file ()
  (interactive)
  (magit-status-autorefresh 'counsel-projectile-find-file)
  )

(defun my/other-ace-window ()
  (interactive)
  (magit-status-autorefresh 'ace-window)
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

You can actually customize how **Magit** shows `magit-status` by setting the `magit-display-buffer-function` variable.

If I correctly understood your question, you're probably looking for `magit-display-buffer-same-window-except-diff-v1` set to that variable.

You can set this variable manually, or press <kbd>C-h v magit-dispaly-buffer-function RET</kbd> and use [Easy Customization](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html).

FYI, you can also implement your own way for **Magit** to show buffers:

```
(setq magit-display-buffer-function
      (lambda (buffer)          
       ;; Go on
      ))
```